# Friendly way to get rid of screeching birds

Tags: home, comfort, pest-control, sound

So I live in an apartment building attic and there's a bird nest right outside, on the roof. They probably just hatched eggs because they screech and scream like they're dying all from 05:00 till 08:00.

I can't actually see the nest, but it's quite close and with this thin roof it's like they are right next to my bed :p

Is there a way to get rid of them in a friendly way? Making them reconsider their choice of nesting? I'm thinking something like a predator sound I can put on or something. I can't really go out on the roof, it's crazy high and no entry hatch.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you can. Once the babies hatch your just gonna have to wait for them to leave the nest.

Comment: What about ultrasounds... I'm going to investigate and try and chase my birds with ultrasounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's a non-protected bird, you could scare them away with movement or sound.

You stated you can't reach there, but you don't have to. A ventilator on a stick produces a lot of air movement and noise. If the distance is too big to cross with a stick, you may consider using a drone (birds don't like quadcopters).

A speaker could be useful but possibly provide problems with the neighbours.

Comment: Oh that sounds interesting. A quadcopter drone would definitely move them away to another rooftop and it's friendly! I really don't think they are protected birds, probably. But if I have a camera on the copter I can have a look at what bird it is and leave them alone if they are protected. Great idea.

Answer (score 6):

Quoting from [this page](http://www.birds.cornell.edu/AllAboutBirds/faq/season/summer/document_view):

> Birds are very sensitive to their environment during the breeding season. In particular, you take a big risk when you move a nest, even if you move it a short distance. The bird may abandon the nest and anything in it. Additionally, it is illegal to disturb the nests of birds protected under the federal Migratory Bird Treaty Act.

Doesn't sound like there's anything you can do until the young are gone.

Comment: Oh darn. Perhaps I'll just need to invest in some ear plugs and stuff.

Comment: @miphe Afraid so. In the future, if you see them starting to build a nest, feel free to knock it down. As long as they haven't yet laid eggs, they'll just go elsewhere.

Answer (score 6):

Get a plastic raven and place it somewhere they can see it. It will frighten them off. If the thought of the little birds starving bothers you, wait till the chicks have flown the nest, and prevent the next brood from starting.

I got a plastic raven to scare off sparrows from nesting in my gutter. You have to place it so it's visible from above, and you have to move it occasionally.

Comment: I see, so a bigger fake bird works as a scarecrow for the smaller birds. Though for the current chicks I'll need to just deal with it.

Comment: A scare-raven. It really works.

Comment: By checking local laws, you may find that the type of bird that is nesting is invasive and/or a pest.  An unfriendly solution may be warranted.

Comment: OK, why the downvote? Tell me what I did wrong?