# How to get rid of frequent nesting by pigeons?

Tags: cleaning, safety, house-cleaning

I have a duct area adjacent to my bathroom window which is unapproachable - almost 2.5 meters down.  Every month pigeons intrude into that space and lay eggs, and their shit generates a filthy smell. My son is also allergic to dust. I can not close the window as that's the only fresh air window feasible for bathroom. Since my flat is at 5th floor and this duct area is approachable only by fire-safety lift, it costs me about 2000 bucks for each cleaning every two months. I can not install a grill or mesh because it's a society controlled area and also may need to used for emergency repairs in my absence.  Can anyone help me with any tactic that can scare the pigeons and prevent their entry into the space - some buzzer or other tactic?

Comment: Related: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/92086/38002

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repel pigeons from roosting on my apartment balcony?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/20651/how-can-i-repel-pigeons-from-roosting-on-my-apartment-balcony)

Answer (score 1):

A picture might help us to imagine it, but if it's reachable even with a long pole, you might be able to get pigeon spikes glued in there.

If you have to pay guys to get up there to clean it, they could maybe do the install too, once it's clean.

[Random google online store with selection.](https://www.pestfix.co.uk/pigeon-spikes.asp)

If it needs access then maybe a clip-in grille instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are [laser devices](https://bird-x.com/bird-products/lasers) that claim to repel birds, but at $US350, I'd not buy one without guarantee of *full* refund if not effective. You can also hang old metallized CD and DVD from thin cords if there is a spot they can catch and reflect sunlight into the duct.

Why would anyone object to a coarse, lightweight mesh, such as [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07RN3LHXG) or [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07F2VDCDL)? You should include a photo of the situation for more ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with pigeons. I have tried artificial eagle, stickers on the glass, balloons with eyes, specific sprays. Nothing helped.
The last and only solution was to put a net over my balcony. It was done by a professional company which put it tightly.

Finally I was able to leave on holidays without worry that pigeon family will create a house in my balcony.

[image: Wire netting over balcony]